# Draw gradient layer in drawInRect

Tags: ios, drawing, drawrect, cagradientlayer

I am trying to develop a costum view which composite version of it contains a costum UIView which contains a gradient layer. Now I want to draw this layer in my new costum view's drawInRect function but I am not sure how should I do it.

My previous custum view with gradient layer:

```
@interface ViewWithGradientLayer : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) CAGradientLayer *layer;

@end

@implementation ViewWithGradientLayer

@dynamic layer;

+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [CAGradientLayer class];
}

@end
```

When I want to use this view I was doing:

```
UIColor *startColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.00 green:0.00 blue:0.02 alpha:1.0];
UIColor *endColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.gradientBackground.layer.colors = @[(__bridge id) endColor.CGColor, (__bridge id) startColor.CGColor];
[self.gradientBackground.layer setStartPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0)];
[self.gradientBackground.layer setEndPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)];
```

Now I have added same layer property to my new custom view which I want to draw the layer in drawInRect:

```
@interface UIBPVCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) CAGradientLayer *layer;

@end

@implementation UIBPVCell

@dynamic layer;

+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [CAGradientLayer class];
}

- (void)commonInit {
    UIColor *startColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.00 green:0.00 blue:0.02 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *endColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.layer.frame = newsImageRect;
    self.layer.colors = @[(__bridge id) endColor.CGColor, (__bridge id) startColor.CGColor];
    [self.layer setStartPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0)];
    [self.layer setEndPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)];
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    NSLog(@"UIBPVCell : initWithFrame");
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
    //How to draw layer here?
}
```

My composite implementation is working fine but this one doesn't. I had tried folowwing but is couse infinite loop:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
    [self.layer drawInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I have found an answer that is similar to selected answer already. Here is my solution:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"UIBPVCell : drawRect");
    [super drawRect:rect];

    if (_newsImage) {
        [_newsImage drawInRect:newsImageRect];

    } else [placeHolderImage drawInRect:newsImageRect];

    CGFloat colors [] = {
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //Start color: Clear color
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.00f, 0.5f //End color: Black with alpha
    };

    CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colors, NULL, 2);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(newsImageRect), CGRectGetMinY(newsImageRect));
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(newsImageRect), CGRectGetMaxY(newsImageRect));
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a gradient layer or drawing a gradient in draw rect is quite different. To draw the gradient in `drawRect` you should try something like the following:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    UIColor *startColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:.0f blue:.0f alpha:1.0f];
    UIColor *endColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.0f green:1.0f blue:.0f alpha:1.0f];

    NSArray *colors = @[(__bridge id)startColor.CGColor, (__bridge id)endColor.CGColor];
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), (CFArrayRef)colors, nil);

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), gradient, CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height), kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation|kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
}
```

Overriding `drawRect` is on a bit lower level so you may not use most of layer calls inside it without creating a loop.